# How to navigate using selenium Webdriver without being logged out?

Tags: python, webdriver

I have managed to log into a website using webdriver. Now that I am logged in, I would like to navigate to a new URL on the same site using `driver.get()`. However, often (not all the time) in doing so I am logged out of the website. I have tried to duplicate the cookies after navigating to the new url, however, I still get the same problem. I am unsure if this method should work / if I am doing it correctly.

```
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
driver.get(link)
timer(time_limit)
for i in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(i)
```

How can I navigate to a different part of the website (without clicking links on the screen)  whilst maintaining my log-in session?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to refresh the page after adding the cookies: `driver.refresh()`